# uncaughtException: Callback was already called in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

im try with this code and trying to get data and sending it to next call back function

getting this error uncaughtException: Callback was already called in node js

```
 function (results, done) {
      // sales manager condition
      var companysalesId = [];
      if (results && results.length > 0 && req.tokenInfo && req.tokenInfo.loginType === 'employee' && req.tokenInfo.role === config.roleData.sm) {
        results.forEach(function (v, i) {
          var userJson = { active: true, salesRep: { '$in': v._id } };
          User.find(userJson).exec(function (err, users) {
            if (err) {
              console1.error('Error:User:UsersResults: ' + errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err));
              return res.status(config.errorStatus).send({ 'errorCode': config.statusCodes.ERROR, errorMessage: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) });
            } else {
              if (users && users.length > 0) {
                users.forEach(function (val, ind) {
                  companysalesId.push(val.companyId);
                });
              }
              if (filter.filter && !filter.filter.companyId) {
                filter.filter.companyId = { '$in': companysalesId };
              }
              done();
            }
          });
        });
      } else if (results && results.length == 0) {
        if (filter.filter && !filter.filter.companyId) {
          filter.filter.companyId = { '$in': companysalesId };
        }
        done();
      } else {
        done();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! The problem is that you executing the callback in a `forEach` loop. No wonder it complains about multiple callbacks.

What you should really do (assuming this is an Express handler function) is just move the `done` callback out of the loop:

```
if (results && results.length > 0 && req.tokenInfo && req.tokenInfo.loginType === 'employee' && req.tokenInfo.role === config.roleData.sm) {
  results.forEach(function (v, i) {
    var userJson = { active: true, salesRep: { '$in': v._id } };
    User.find(userJson).exec(function (err, users) {
      if (err) {
        console1.error('Error:User:UsersResults: ' + errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err));
        return res.status(config.errorStatus).send({ 'errorCode': config.statusCodes.ERROR, errorMessage: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) });
      } else {
        if (users && users.length > 0) {
          users.forEach(function (val, ind) {
            companysalesId.push(val.companyId);
          });
        }
        if (filter.filter && !filter.filter.companyId) {
          filter.filter.companyId = { '$in': companysalesId };
        }
      }
    });
  });
  done();
}
```

Other than that, you should try to always `return` the callback:

```
return done();
```

So you will actually halt the execution and won't get yourself into situations like this.